# Executors distribution of task per threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am fairly new with java executors, so this maybe an easy question.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NumberOfThreads - 1);

        do_work();  
        for(int i = 1; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
        {
            executorService.execute(new Runnable() 
            {                                   
                public void run()
                {
                    do_work();  
                }
            });             
        }
```

My question is:

If I create a fixed thread pool with 'N' threads, and if I want to execute 'N' tasks, like the code above. Do I have guarantees that each thread will only execute one task (do_work())?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's a pool, and the assignment of threads to tasks doesn't make such guarantees.

e.g. imagine your `do_work()` method completes immediately. By the time you submit your 2nd Runnable, all the threads in the pool will be available, and any one of them will be a candidate for your job.